# two monitors and black screen on loki 0.4.1

Tags: display

I have two monitors, after locking screen and new login attept to the system both monitors show me a black screen. It happens from time to time. What can i do?

$ uname -r
4.4.0-97-generic

$ lsb_release -a -u
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki
Release:    0.4.1
Codename:   loki

Answer (score 0):

This seems a problem with the gpu driver. What gpu are you using and what kind of driver opensource or closed?

Comment: Driver closed, NVIDIA Binary Driver 384.90

Comment: lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5912 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)